# How many equivalence classes does the following equivalence relation (over permutations) have?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, equivalence-relations

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Consider the set of all permutations over $n$.
Two permutations $\pi_1 = i_1..i_n$ and $\pi_2 = j_1..j_n$ are **not** equivalent if either $i_n i_1$ appears in $\pi_2$ (that is, $\exists k: j_k=i_n \land j_{k+1}=i_1$) or $j_n j_1$ appears in $\pi_1$. How many equivalence classes there are?

Comment: Can you be more specific about "$i_ni_1$ appears in $\pi_2$"? Are you saying $\exists k : j_k = i_n \wedge j_{k+1} = i_1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question cannot be answered because it assumed a false premise. The operation you described is not an equivalence relation, because it violates transitivity:

$$(1, 2, 3, 4) = (4, 3, 2, 1) = (3, 4, 1, 2)$$
$$(1, 2, 3, 4) \neq (3, 4, 1, 2)$$